# How to compress and decompress a .tar.gz with zlib and nodejs

Tags: node.js, tar, zlib, gzip

I am pretty sure this is quite a dumb question. However, I am in need to take a folder and compress it to a `.tar.gz` file using (if possible) only the `zlib` library of Node. Symmetrically, I would then need to decompress the `.tar.gz` file to a given destination folder.

I looked around but I could not find any reasonable solution to the problem that doesn't make use of external libraries, which I would like to avoid. If this cannot be done with `.tar.gz`, but can be done with *any* other compression method using just `zlib`, it would be great if you could tell me.

Any snippet or example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unless you're going to implement the TAR format yourself, you need to either use an external lib _or_ an external program to create the ".tar" part of your file.

Answer (score 4):

zlib will handle the ".gz" part for you, but not the ".tar" part. The [tar format](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html) is not terribly complicated, so it should be straightforward to roll your own. It's just a 512 byte header before each file, the file padded out to a multiple of 512 bytes, repeated for each file, and ended with two 512-byte blocks of all zeros.

You would then use zlib to compress that using the gzip method.